# Adding Entity Objects to LINQ-to-SQL Data Context at Runtime - SQL, C#(WPF)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq-to-sql

I've hit a wall when it comes to adding a new entity object (a regular SQL table) to the Data Context using LINQ-to-SQL.  This isn't regarding the drag-and-drop method that is cited regularly across many other threads.  This method has worked repeatedly without issue.

The end goal is relatively simple.  I need to find a way to add a table that gets created *during runtime* via stored procedure to the current Data Context of the LINQ-to-SQL dbml file.  I'll then need to be able to use the regular LINQ query methods/extension methods (InsertOnSubmit(), DeleteOnSubmit(), Where(), Contains(), FirstOrDefault(), etc...) on this new table object through the existing Data Context.  Essentially, I need to find a way to procedurally create the code that would otherwise be automatically generated when you do use the drag-and-drop method during development (when the application isn't running), but have it generate this same code while the application is running via command and/or event trigger.

### More Detail

There's one table that gets used a lot and, over the course of an entire year, collects many thousands of rows.  Each row contains a timestamp and this table needs to be divided into multiple tables based on the year that the row was added.

**Current Solution (using one table)**

- Single table with tens of thousands of rows which are constantly queried against.
- Table is added to Data Context during development using drag-and-drop, so there are no additional coding issues
- Significant performance decrease over time

**Goals (using multiple tables)**

- (Complete) While the application is running, use C# code to check if a table for the current year already exists.  If it does, no action is taken.  If not, a new table gets created using a stored procedure with the current year as a prefix on the table name (2017_TableName, 2018_TableName, 2019_TableName, and so on...).
- (Incomplete) While the application is still running, add the newly created table to the active LINQ-to-SQL Data Context (the same code that would otherwise be added using drag-and-drop during development).
- (Incomplete) Run regular LINQ queries against the newly added table.

**Final Thoughts**

Other than the above, my only other concern is how to write the C# code that references a table that may or may not already exist.  Is it possible to use a variable in place of the standard 'DB_DataContext.2019_TableName' methodology in order to actually get the table's data into a UI control?  Is there a way to simply create an Enumerable of all the tables where the name is prefixed with a year and then select the most current table?

From what I've read so far, the most likely solution seems to involve the use of a SQL add-on like SQLMetal or Huagati which (based solely from what I've read) will generate the code I need during runtime and update the corresponding dbml file.  I have no experience using these types of add-ons, so any additional insight into these would be appreciated.

Lastly, I've seen some references to LINQ-to-Entities and/or LINQ-to-Objects.  Would these be the components I'm looking for?

Thanks for reading through a rather lengthy first post.  Any comments/criticisms are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to redirect in SQL Server, and leave your client code alone.  At design-time create your L2S Data Context, or EF DbContex referencing a database with only a single table.  Then at run-time substitue a view or synonym for that table that points to the "current year" table.

HOWEVER this should not be necessary in the first place.  SQL Server supports [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15), so you can *store* all the data in a physically separate data structures, but have a single logical table.  And SQL Server supports [columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2014) tables, which can compress and store many millions of rows with excellent performance.